# Удалить выделенные элементы из Listbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter

Есть список индексов всех выбранных элементов:

```
list1 = listbox1.curselection()
```

Как правильно удалить эти выбранные элементы за 1 раз из `listbox1` на *Python*, библиотека *tkinter*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно удалить можно в цикле. Но цикл нужно проходить в сторону уменьшения индексов, иначе элементы будут удаляться неправильно. При удалении какого-либо элемента у следующих изменится индекс и он уже не будет соответствовать тому, что получено в `curselection`.

```
import tkinter


def callback():
    for i in reversed(listbox.curselection()):
        listbox.delete(i)

tk = tkinter.Tk()

listbox = tkinter.Listbox(tk, selectmode=tkinter.EXTENDED)
listbox.pack()


button = tkinter.Button(tk, text="Delete", command=callback)
button.pack()

for item in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]:
    listbox.insert(tkinter.END, item)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, работает